# Show that $b\ge f_{n+1}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, fractions, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is defined as $f_1=f_2=1, f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_{n}$. Assume that ${f_n \over f_{n-1}} \lt {a \over b} \lt {f_{n+1} \over f_n}$ ($a$ and $b$ are positive integers with no common prime factors). Show that $b\ge f_{n+1}$.

Comment: Are a and b constrained in some way? (I.e., do they have to be integers?)

Comment: Yes, integers, let me edit that.

Comment: is a/b irreductible.

Comment: I think it should be strict inequality as if u take $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$. it is a contradiction

Comment: The comment of user @Vishnu N is right. If $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}$ then it's contradition to $b\geq f_{n+1}$.

Comment: I'd love to prove this by showing that the Euclidean algorithm for computing $\gcd(a,b)$ takes $n$ steps. It is well know that this implies $b\ge f_{n+1}$.

Comment: @lhf how to prove that for every $n$ there are coprime integer numbers $a$ and $b$ such that ${f_n \over f_{n-1}} \lt {a \over b} \lt {f_{n+1} \over f_n}$?

Comment: @Amin235, just take their mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark:** 
*$\frac{f_{r+1}}{f_{r}}$ are convergents of the continued fraction of $\varphi$ the golden ratio. There is a theorem that any convergent is nearer to the number (whose CF we are looking at) than any other rational with a smaller denominator. That or something similar can potentially be used here.*

---

**Anyway, here is a simple proof that $b \ge f_{n+1}$**

> First we show that $b \gt f_n$.

Subtract $\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$ from the given inequality to get

$$0 \lt \frac{a}{b} - \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} \lt \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} - \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{f_nf_{n-1}}$$

We used the identity $|f_{n+1}f_{n-1} - f_n^2| = 1$ ([Cassini's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities)) to simplify the right hand side.

i.e

$$ 0 \lt \frac{af_{n-1} - bf_n}{b} \lt \frac{1}{f_{n}}$$

And so

$$ b \gt f_n(af_{n-1} - bf_n)$$

Now $af_{n-1} - bf_n$ is a positive integer and so is $\ge 1$ and so $b \gt f_{n}$

> Now we show that $b \ge f_{n+1}$.

Now if $af_{n-1} - bf_n \ge 2$, then we will have $b \gt 2 f_n \gt f_n + f_{n-1} = f_{n+1}$.

So assume that $$af_{n-1} - b f_n = 1$$

Now all solutions of $$au + bv = 1$$ are given by

$$a_t = a_0 + tv$$ 
$$b_t = b_0 - tu$$

where $t$ is an integer param, and $a_0, b_0$ are some initial solution.

For us (again using Cassini's) $$a_0 = f_{n+1}$$ $$b_0 = f_n$$ $$u = f_{n-1}$$ $$v = -f_n$$

Thus the solutions are 
$$a_t = f_{n+1} - tf_n$$ 
$$ b_t = f_n - t f_{n-1}$$

Since we want  $$b_t \gt f_n$$ we need $t \lt 0$ in which case $$b = b_t \ge f_n + f_{n-1} = f_{n+1}$$

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation below "i.e."?

Comment: The typo has been corrected.

Comment: Excellent proof! +1

Comment: @Hans: Thanks! Was surprised it turned out to be simple. I was expecting this might require some heavyweight continued fraction theorems.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is surprising. I wonder if there are any other problems that are solved with similar techniques, beyond this particular problem relying on Cassini's formula.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a,a',a''$ are non-negative integers and $b,b',b''$ are positive integers with $a''b'-b''a'=1$ and $\frac {a'}{b'}<\frac {a}{b}<\frac {a''}{b''}.$ Then $$0<ab'-a'b \quad \text { and }\quad 0<a''b-ab''.$$ Since these are all integers we have $$1\leq ab'-a'b \quad \text { and }\quad 1\leq a''b-ab''.$$ Multiplying the left inequality above by $b'',$ and multiplying the right inequality above by $b'$ we have $$b''\leq b''ab'-b''a'b \quad \text { and }\quad b'\leq b'a''b-b'a'b''.$$ Adding the above two inequalities we have  $$b''+b'\leq (b''ab'-b''a'b)+(b'a''b-b'ab'')=b(a''b'-b''a')=b.$$

Since $f_n^2-f_{n-1}f_{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1},$ if $(a',b')=(f_n,f_{n-1})$ and $(a'',b'')=(f_{n+1},f_n)$ and if $\frac {a''}{b''}>\frac {a'}{b'}$, then  $a''b'-b''a'=1.$

Comment: +1: This is even simpler and essentially proves that for any rational between two consecutive convergents of a CF, the smallest denominator possible is same as the denominator of the mediant of the two convergents.

Comment: @Aryabhata . See "Farey series".  Using Farey series, we can easily show that for any  irrational real $x$ and any $r>0$ there are infinitely many integers $a,b,c,d$  with $x-r<a/b<x<c/d<x+r$ and $1/\psi<|b/d|<\psi$ (where $\psi$ is the Golden Ratio). From that, we easily show there are infinitely many integers $e,f$ with $|x-e/f|<(\psi f^2)^{-1}.$

Comment: Yeah, there is a close resemblance there! btw, are you talking about Hurwitz's theorem in the last sentence? Isn't it $\sqrt{5}$ and not the golden ratio?

Comment: @Aryabhata. Yes . It should be $\sqrt 5$, not $\psi$, in the last sentence. It's not a result that I know by any  name.